# I keep getting this issue when trying to upload my app

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWua4.png)

I keep getting this error when I try to upload my app. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode can download a new signing identity for you. Just go to Xcode > Preferences, then select the "Accounts" tab. Select your account on the left, click "View Details…" on the bottom right, and for the iOS signing identity select "Download".